# PowerShell - Return the list of Hyper-V virtual machines (before a pause)

Tags: powershell

it's been a few days since I started a PowerShell script project allowing the management of Hyper-V virtual machines via PowerShell.

Unfortunately, I was confronted with a problem, and despite my little experience with PowerShell (about 1 year) I do not understand where this "bug" (?) comes from.

More precisely, I know where the bug comes from but I do not understand it.

*Whether it is in a function.*

```
function Get_VMs
{
Get-VM|Select-Object -Property Name,State
pause
}
Get_VMs
```

*Or out of a function.*

```
Get-VM;pause
```

Or

```
Get-VM
pause
```

**In short, the problem is this, the pause is displayed BEFORE the VMs are displayed.**

[As you can see, the pause runs before Get-VM, at least the output of Get-VM arrives after the pause.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE74l.png)

The problem remains the same with a Read-Host.

**For some, the problem may seem obvious, but whatever happens, I thank you in advance for your answer.**

*I wish you all an excellent day or evening.*

Comment: Pipe `Get-VM |Select ...` to `| Out-Default` - this will force powershell.exe to render the output to the screen buffer before executing `pause`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, can you explain me how it solves the problem? I can see that it works but I would like to understand why, for what reason, by default PowerShell first displays the pause before the Get-VM output?

Comment: Highest-voted answer to the post I've linked to explains it - the host application delays rendering of the first output object whereas `pause` write directly to the screen buffer, hence this perculiar timing issue.